# No package 'lua' found but i have it installed

Tags: ubuntu, lua, pkg-config

I'm trying to install *Lsyncd* on **Ubuntu 10.4 LTS** but i get some error :

```
> checking for LUA... no checking for
> LUA... no checking for LUA...
> configure: error: Package requirements
> (lua >= 5.1.3) were not met:
> 
> No package 'lua' found
> 
> Consider adjusting the PKG_CONFIG_PATH
> environment variable if you installed
> software in a non-standard prefix.
> 
> Alternatively, you may set the
> environment variables LUA_CFLAGS and
> LUA_LIBS to avoid the need to call
> pkg-config. See the pkg-config man
> page for more details.
```

Or I know I have **Lua** installed :

```
# lua -v
Lua 5.1.4  Copyright (C) 1994-2008 Lua.org, PUC-Rio
```

I read on several forums that I need a lua.pc file but i can't find it. Does anyone know how to proceed?

Thank you

**EDIT : SOLVED**

Some packages were missing ;)

```
apt-get install liblua5.1-0-dev liblua50-dev liblualib50-dev
```

Comment: You don't need the '50' if you're using Lua 5.1. Those are for Lua 5.0.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

If compiling software yourself, you should install not only the runtime (lua5.1) but also the development packages (liblua5.1-0-dev). That package contains the lua5.1.pc file.

It's also in the [lua source distribution](http://www.lua.org/download.html).

Comment: Had to add a link to the correct config-file. 
sudo ln -s /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/pkgconfig/lua5.1.pc /usr/lib/pkgconfig/lua.pc

Answer (score 8):

try 
`sudo apt-get install liblua5.1-0-dev`

Answer (score 8):

I met the same problem on my debian jessie while trying to compile luacrypto.

The problem is, in configure.ac, luacrypto try the following:

```
PKG_CHECK_MODULES([LUA], [lua])
LUALIBDIR="`$PKGCONFIG --variable=libdir lua`"
```

The problem is that, since there's multiple versions available, you need to specify which one you want, here is my output for pkg-config --list-all:

```
root@test-stream:~/luacrypto# pkg-config --list-all|grep -i lua
lua-5.1-c++      Lua - Lua language engine
lua-5.1          Lua - Lua language engine
lualib50         lua50 - The Lua 5.0 programming language addon libraries
lua5.1           Lua - Lua language engine
lua5.1-c++       Lua - Lua language engine
lua51            Lua - Lua language engine
lua50            lua50 - The Lua 5.0 programming language
lua51-c++        Lua - Lua language engine
```

I just modified top-level configure.ac for luacrypto this way:

```
diff --git a/configure.ac b/configure.ac
index b6b9175..20ea20c 100644
--- a/configure.ac
+++ b/configure.ac
@@ -28,10 +28,10 @@ AC_CHECK_FUNCS([memset])

 # pkgconfig
 PKG_CHECK_MODULES([OPENSSL], [openssl])
-PKG_CHECK_MODULES([LUA], [lua])
+PKG_CHECK_MODULES([LUA], [lua5.1])

 # lua libdir
-LUALIBDIR="`$PKGCONFIG --variable=libdir lua`"
+LUALIBDIR="`$PKGCONFIG --variable=libdir lua5.1`"
```

Then autoreconf -i (you need autoconf & automake for this) and it works !

Comment: You're my hero!

Comment: How such "reported error" could persists until now on Debian 10 (bullseye) - from 12 years ago?

Comment: Maybe the problem is nobody reported it to Debian ? 
I didn't (yes i should have, but was a but hurried at work).

Answer (score -1):

It seems you have installed **Lua**.

The missing `lua5.1.pc` file will be present in the **etc** folder
To install the other missing packages try the below command

```
sudo apt-get install libreadline-dev
```