# What is the development package for lua 5.1.4?

Tags: linux, lua

My machine has `lua-5.1.4` installed (from source) but does not have `lua.pc`. What is the development package to download for `lua 5.1.4`?

I am new to this myself, so please bear with me while I explain what is 'lua.pc'. If you think some of the information here is incorrect, please make full use of the edit button.

`lua.pc` or any file with `pc` for an extension is a file that goes into either `/usr/local/lib/pkgconfig/` or `/usr/lib/pkgconfig` directories. It is a text file containing different fields such as `Description` etc., information that is used by the `make install` process. The default installation of `lua` does not install the `lua.pc` file. That is because it is the 'normal' package. However, the development package contains this file. The development package creates additional dynamic links (for shared libraries etc.) that are needed during installation of other software where these shared libraries may be dependencies. For more information, read [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5350086/no-package-lua-found-but-i-have-it-installed) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7482400/linking-sdl-image-errors/7482818#7482818).

**Update:** `lua.pc` is present in the `etc/` folder within the source tarball.

Comment: What is `lua.pc`? And what is a "development package?"

Comment: @NicolBolas: I have tried to add some more information. Please take a look at it. The explanation is not perfect, and I myself have been introduced to these things today.

Comment: Which distro are you using, and where/how did you obtain the Lua package?

Comment: @tripleee: I am using `Fedora11` and obtained Lua package from the main website for Lua itself. Please see @jpjacobs answer. It seems that is correct.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The lua.pc is in the [source tarbal](http://www.lua.org/ftp/lua-5.1.4.tar.gz), in the `etc` folder

Comment: aarrrrrghhh!! please allow me a moment while I kick myself! Copying `lua.pc` into `/usr/lib/pkgconfig/` does seem to work. But what is the difference between `/usr/lib/pkgconfig` and `/usr/local/lib/pkgconfig`?

Comment: `/usr/` is normally maintained by the system tools (like apt in debian), while the (super)user is free to do whatever he wants with `/usr/local/`, without interference with normal system processes/ package tools. More info in the [Rute guide](http://rute.2038bug.com/node38.html.gz#SECTION003840000000000000000)