# configure: error: lua-libs not found

Tags: lua, gnu-make, raspbian

I have a Raspbian distribution with `liblua5.2-dev` manually installed:

```
sudo apt-get install lua5.2 liblua5.2-dev liblua50-dev liblualib50-dev
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
liblua5.2-dev is already the newest version.
lua5.2 is already the newest version.
The following extra packages will be installed:
  liblua50 liblualib50 lua50
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  liblua50 liblua50-dev liblualib50 liblualib50-dev lua50
0 upgraded, 5 newly installed, 0 to remove and 11 not upgraded.
Need to get 194 kB of archives.
After this operation, 413 kB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
Get:1 http://mirrordirector.raspbian.org/raspbian/ jessie/main liblua50 armhf 5.0.3-7 [45.3 kB]
Get:2 http://mirrordirector.raspbian.org/raspbian/ jessie/main liblualib50 armhf 5.0.3-7 [31.0 kB]
Get:3 http://mirrordirector.raspbian.org/raspbian/ jessie/main lua50 armhf 5.0.3-7 [25.7 kB]  
Get:4 http://mirrordirector.raspbian.org/raspbian/ jessie/main liblua50-dev armhf 5.0.3-7 [55.4 kB]
Get:5 http://mirrordirector.raspbian.org/raspbian/ jessie/main liblualib50-dev armhf 5.0.3-7 [36.2 kB]
Fetched 194 kB in 2s (87.6 kB/s)      
Selecting previously unselected package liblua50.
(Reading database ... 119455 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../liblua50_5.0.3-7_armhf.deb ...
Unpacking liblua50 (5.0.3-7) ...
Selecting previously unselected package liblualib50.
Preparing to unpack .../liblualib50_5.0.3-7_armhf.deb ...
Unpacking liblualib50 (5.0.3-7) ...
Selecting previously unselected package lua50.
Preparing to unpack .../lua50_5.0.3-7_armhf.deb ...
Unpacking lua50 (5.0.3-7) ...
Selecting previously unselected package liblua50-dev.
Preparing to unpack .../liblua50-dev_5.0.3-7_armhf.deb ...
Unpacking liblua50-dev (5.0.3-7) ...
Selecting previously unselected package liblualib50-dev.
Preparing to unpack .../liblualib50-dev_5.0.3-7_armhf.deb ...
Unpacking liblualib50-dev (5.0.3-7) ...
Processing triggers for man-db (2.7.5-1~bpo8+1) ...
Setting up liblua50 (5.0.3-7) ...
Setting up liblualib50 (5.0.3-7) ...
Setting up lua50 (5.0.3-7) ...
Setting up liblua50-dev (5.0.3-7) ...
update-alternatives: using /usr/bin/lua-config50 to provide /usr/bin/lua-config (lua-configuration) in auto mode
Setting up liblualib50-dev (5.0.3-7) ...
Processing triggers for libc-bin (2.19-18+deb8u10) ...
```

When I check `Lua`:

```
Lua 5.2.3 Copyright (C) 1994-2013 Lua.org. PUC-Rio
```

I am trying to compile [Janus](https://github.com/meetecho/janus-gateway) but cannot get `Gnu Make (4.0)` configuration to complete without error (from within Janus directory):

```
...
checking for usrsctp_finish in -lusrsctp... no
checking for LIBCURL... yes
checking for doxygen... no
checking for dot... no
checking for gengetopt... yes
checking for TRANSPORTS... yes
checking for MHD... yes
checking for lws_create_vhost in -lwebsockets... no
checking for amqp_error_string2 in -lrabbitmq... no
checking for MQTTAsync_create in -lpaho-mqtt3a... no
checking for nn_socket in -lnanomsg... no
checking for PLUGINS... yes
checking for SOFIA... yes
checking for LIBRE... no
checking for LIBRE... no
checking for OPUS... yes
checking for OGG... yes
checking for LUA... no
checking for LUA... no
configure: error: lua-libs not found. See README.md for installation instructions or use --disable-plugin-lua
```

I have read the README.md, which makes no mention of Lua.

I have reviewed many posts on the subject, but none remedy issue:

- [No package 'lua' found but i have it installed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5350086/no-package-lua-found-but-i-have-it-installed)
- https://github.com/simoncozens/sile/issues/296
- Raspbian is a Debian distro, [so I thought this might help.](https://otland.net/threads/linux-ultimate-compile-guide-for-debian-ubuntu-included.2868/page-19)

All assume headers missing, but none specifically point to how to get headers - only advise installing dev package to get them, which I have done.

**Are there missing or incorrectly set environment variables?  What is missing from my understanding on this?**

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the [configure.ac file in the Janus source](https://github.com/meetecho/janus-gateway/blob/master/configure.ac#L707), I see that the error you are seeing happens when PKG_CHECK_MODULES fails for both "lua" and "lua5.3".  There's no check for "lua5.2".

You could install liblua5.3-dev, or modify configure.ac to look for lua5.2.